# C# MVC pass data from one action method to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to pass data from one Action to another in the same Controller.But always it is coming as null

Action1

```
ViewData["page"] = pageData;
```

Action2

```
var pageData = ViewData["page"];//Always Null
```

I have following requirement.

1. Hit page and call **Action1**
2. For same browser session store **pageData** in ViewData
3. There will be one button on the page which will call **Action2**
4. use **ViewData["page"]** to get pageData value which we have assign in 
   **Action1**

Could anyone please help me to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try `TempData`:

```
TempData["page"] = pageData;
```

> ViewBag and ViewData are used to pass data from controller to view.
>
> TempData is used to pass data from the current request to the next
>   request.

For additional info on difference you can refer to this link [Difference Between ViewData, ViewBag and TempData](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata1).

Comment: I have tried TempData["page"] = pageData as well but not working for me. have kept TempData.Keep() as well. but no luck

Comment: I tried to replicate it on my machine and it is working fine the same with your posted scenario. Are you sure that the next request was the Action method Action2? If not, TempData will be automatically null. Since TempData works only on "concurrent" request.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag or ViewData only lives from one controller action to the View.

To access the value in the next immediate action, try using TempData with the similar syntax as ViewData

Comment: I have tried TempData["page"] = pageData as well but not working for me. have kept TempData.Keep() as well. but no luck

Comment: is there any other action method being called between these 2 .. like in ajax ?

Comment: Nope. there is no another action method

Comment: does the value exists when setting it?
try passing as a hiiden field from view to the next controller :)

Answer (score 0):

What you going to do is To fill the `ViewData["page"]` Within the your action then pass it to View. since it only lives within your `Controller [Action] -> View`. then Store it within an element (It can be a Hidden Input) like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value=@ViewData["page"] id="ID" />
```

Then If you wish to receive it Within your Next ActionResult you can easily Call the `FormCollection` like below and take the Value from the Hidden Input:

```
public ActionResult Example(FormCollection form)
{
    var id = form["ID"];
}
```

Thats how it works with ViewData and ViewBag. **However**; If you want to Directly use the data within another action I recommend using `TempData` like below:

```
TempData["page"] = pageData;
```

There are number of other ways to receive the data within your other action as well such as `Cookies`, And `Sessions` but Unless you do not want to go to many trouble i recommend `TempData`.

**UPDATE**

Use `Session`, Next easiest option would be `Session` It works like below:

Create:

```
Session["page"] = YourValue;
```

Read:

```
//You can easy cast it to your type or Convert it.
var _strValue = Sessions["page"].ToString() //if its string
```

Comment: I have tried TempData["page"] = pageData as well but not working for me. have kept TempData.Keep() as well. but no luck

Comment: @ChirayuBrahmbhatt Create a Session and Call the Session and receive your data, Let me update my Answer.

Comment: @ChirayuBrahmbhatt updated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
TempData["page"] = pageData;
```

it works with multiple actions but only one request.

```
Session["page"] = pageData;
```

works with multiple requests but it more heavy.

i hope this help you.